# Find Values $i^{-i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Using the identity $z^{\alpha} = e^{\alpha \log(z)} = e^{\alpha ( \log|z| + iArg(z) + 2\pi i m)}$, I have,

$$ i^{-i} = e^{-i \log(i) } = e^{-i (0+i\pi/2 + 2\pi m i ) } = e^{-i^2\pi/2 -i^22\pi m} = e^{\pi/2+2\pi m} $$

since $i^2 = -1$. However, the book (Gamelin; CA) says the answer is $e^{\pi/2-2\pi m}$. Where does the minus sign come from? Thank you very much! Appreciate it. :)

Comment: Since $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, the sign is irrelevant in terms of set equality.

Comment: thank you! You're right! 0